# Start and end date of next week swift

Tags: swift, calendar

I need to get date like "31 of January - 6 of February"

I used next code:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let weekday = 1 
let sundayComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, weekday: weekday)

let nextSunday = calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: sundayComponents, matchingPolicy: .nextTimePreservingSmallerComponents)
```

I need to take all this period from Monday to Sunday

[image: I need to take all this period from Monday to Sunday]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dateInterval(of:start:interval:for:)`:

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let calendar: Calendar = .current

let now = Date()
let weekFromNow = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: now)!

var start = weekFromNow
var interval: TimeInterval = 0
guard calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &start, interval: &interval, for: weekFromNow) else { return }

let end = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: start.addingTimeInterval(interval))!
// or let end = start.addingTimeInterval(interval - 1)
// or let end = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: start)!

print(formatter.string(from: start), "-", formatter.string(from: end))
```

This will honor the “start of week” on your device.

Comment: You can use iso8601 calendar to get Monday as the first weekday

Comment: Or you can get `firstWeekday` from your own calendar, too. Why use `iso8601` calendar?

Comment: Of course we can change the firstWeekday.  I prefer using iso8601 because Monday it is the default

Comment: And I generally try to honor the user's choice of start of the week.

Comment: All calendars AFAIK do have Sunday as the first weekday except iso8601

Comment: Yeah, but it’s a question of your locale’s calendar settings. E.g. `Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")` uses a `.gregorian` calendar, but `firstWeekday` is Monday, not Sunday. And even if you're in a locale that generally uses Sunday (like the US), the user can override it. IMHO, you should honor the device localization settings.

Comment: @Rob,  also how can I check are these dates in the same month?

Comment: You can extract the date components, e.g. `let month = calendar.dateComponents([.month], from: date).month!`

Comment: @Rob I live in Ukraine and my week starts on Monday
If I put the Gregorian calendar, your function shows that my week starts from Sunday
How can I fix this?

Comment: In general, don't use fixed calendars. Use the `Calendar.current` which honors your locale settings. That way, it honors your Ukrainian start of week (but for users in other locales, it will honor their calendar settings).

Comment: @Rob you can use calendar's component method for a single component `let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)`

Comment: Yep. And if he wants both month and year (or whatever) then he would use `let components = dateComponents([.month, .year], from: date)`.