# Find out start of next week in swift

Tags: swift

I try to find out the start of the next week in the current calendar the user is in. I've tried

```
    public func nextStartOfWeek() -> Date {
       let next = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: self)!
       let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: next)
       return Calendar.current.nextDate(after: self, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
    }
```

In my locale the week starts on Monday and the scheme of the run profile is set to it. Unfortunately this still results in Sunday as start of the week.

I've used this code in the playground

```
import Foundation

// let s = Date()
let c = Calendar.current

let customDate = DateComponents(calendar: c, timeZone: nil, era: nil, year: 2021, month: 06, day: 15, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: nil, weekday: nil, weekdayOrdinal: nil, quarter: nil, weekOfMonth: nil, weekOfYear: nil, yearForWeekOfYear: nil)
let s = c.date(from: customDate)!

let next = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: s)!

print("Next \(next)")

var components = c.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: next)

print("\(components)")

var startOfNextWeek = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: s, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)

print("Start of next Week \(startOfNextWeek!)")
```

And would expect the 2021-06-20 22:00:00 (I'm UTC+2), unfortunately it's 2021-06-19.

Is there a better way of finding out the start of next week? And what's my error here (in code or brain)?

Comment: This works fine for me in a playground and I believe I am in the same time zone as you.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65908191/1187415

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Have you verified that `Calendar.current.firstWeekday == 2`?

Comment: Calendar.current.firstWeekday == 1 . Any idea why? My system has the correct locale set in system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working (for french calendar) by replacing Calendar.current:

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fr_FR") as Locale

func nextStartOfWeek() -> Date {
       let next = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: self)!
       let components = calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: next)
       return calendar.nextDate(after: self, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
}
```